# i want to have a streaming replication with delay 10 minutes behind the primary

Tags: postgresql-14

I have set up a postgreSQL14 streaming replication. I set recovery_min_apply_delay=5min .
every thing is ok. I have tested scenarious in which i delete some records from primary and i can recover them from standby. but in case of dropping or truncating a table standby database immediately is affected. do you know how i can handle it?